# html5 popstate event can not fired on chrome and ie

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, browser-history

I'm testing in these browsers:

- Chrome 43.0.2357.134 m
- Firefox 39.0
- IE 11

I added the event listener like this

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", callback);
```

and coded to change state like this

```
history.pushState(param, "#")
```

It works in same url page, but after navigating back from another url page the popstate listener is not called (yet it is working on firefox).

I don't know what to do. Is there a solution???

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually replace the state when the initial page loads. 
Something like the following should work.

```
var firstState = { // your initial state
}

function initState() { 
    history.replaceState(firstState);
}

if (document.readyState === 'complete') initState();
else window.onload = initState;
```